# leaflet + gMapCatcher- change zxy template

Tags: leaflet

I'm using `leaflet` with tiles generated by gMapCatcher.
the file names there is totally different.
For example - zoom level 17 in leaflet is level 0 at gMapCatcher.

I need to change the url template

```
'http://{s}.somedomain.com/blabla/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
```

so I can insert the calculations for the right directories

I tried the naive way to write the calculations within the template but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer:

I downloades the leaflet.js (passed it through http://jsbeautifier.org/)
and changed the code at getTileUrl and added my custom variables :

```
getTileUrl: function (t) {
            return o.Util.template(this._url, o.extend({
                s: this._getSubdomain(t),
                z: t.z,
                x: t.x,
                y: t.y,
                z0: 17-t.z,
                x0: Math.floor(t.x/1024),
                x1: Math.floor(t.x%1024),
                y0: Math.floor(t.y/1024),
                y1: Math.floor(t.y%1024)
            }, this.options))
        },
```

and in my script

```
  L.tileLayer('img/tiles/gMapCatcher/{z0}/{x0}/{x1}/{y0}/{y1}.png').addTo(map); //gMapCatcher

    L.tileLayer('img/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
 //other tiles
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I got this working using your recommendation. For anyone else interested I found that gMapCapture put the tiles into 'C:\Users\myUsername\.GMapCatcher\tiles'.

Answer (score 2):

In leaflet 0.7 change the code to

```
getTileUrl: function (t) {
        return L.Util.template(this._url, L.extend({
            s: this._getSubdomain(t),
            z: t.z,
            x: t.x,
            y: t.y,
            z0: 17-t.z,
            x0: Math.floor(t.x/1024),
            x1: Math.floor(t.x%1024),
            y0: Math.floor(t.y/1024),
            y1: Math.floor(t.y%1024)
        }, this.options))
    },
```

otherwise it will give a reference error
And to find the location of gmapcatcher files just go into the settings and find the location

Answer (score 2):

Taking shai givati's answer a step farther, if you don't want to edit the source, this appears to work (although it's not documented as far as I can see):

```
var map = L.map('map');

var layer = L.tileLayer().addTo(map);

layer.getTileUrl = function(coords)
{
    var url = /* whatever logic you'd like to use to come up with a url */;
    return url;
};
```

This has the benefit of working on an individual instance of a tileLayer rather than globally on every layer. Plus, it's more in line with the way other javascript mapping frameworks behave, such as google maps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread, but I needed this today and this was the answer google gave me. The answer Shai Givati gave was very helpful, so I am posting here a way to convert the filenames both ways, if you need to rename them:

```
/*
 * GMapCatcher maptile filename format:
 *   z0/x0/x1/y0/y1.png (e.g. 0/47/78/72/280.png)
 *
 * Leaflet maptile filename format (XYZ):
 *   z/x/y.png (e.g. 17/48206/74008.png)
 */

void LeafletToGMapCatcher( int z, int x, int y )
{
    int z0 = 17 - z;
    int x0 = floor( x / 1024 );
    int x1 = floor( x % 1024 );
    int y0 = floor( y / 1024 );
    int y1 = floor( y % 1024 );
    
    printf( "%d/%d/%d/%d/%d.png\n", z0, x0, x1, y0, y1 );
}

void GMapCatcherToLeaflet( int z0, int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1 )
{
    int z = 17 - z0;
    int x = ( x0 * 1024 ) + x1;
    int y = ( y0 * 1024 ) + y1;
    
    printf( "%d/%d/%d.png\n", z, x, y );
}
```